# Rust stream request cancellation

Tags: asynchronous, rust, streaming, rust-tokio

I have built an endpoint using Rocket library for requesting some resource and streaming it back to the requester, so the code looks like following:

```rust
#[post("/new-stream")]
pub fn my_func() -> EventStream<impl Stream<Item = Event> + '_> {
    EventStream! {
        ...
        let mut stream = client.create_stream(request).await.unwrap();
        while let Some(result) = stream.next().await {
            match result {
                Ok(response) => {
                    ...
                },
                Err(err) => {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

But during a stream, a user may decide to stop streaming, so the request can be cancelled/aborted from the frontend side, but how to handle that in rust code?

In other languages, you have a context and can check whether it's canceled or not, but in Rust I don't see anything like that.

Comment: Use a signal to broadcast -- [tokio::sync::broadcast](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.28.2/tokio/sync/broadcast/index.html#examples) shutdown.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this example? https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/response/stream/index.html#graceful-shutdown

I'm not sure whether it's relevant to server shutdowns or connection shutdowns, and I'm not familiar with Rocket.

Comment: @A.Z. shutdown is triggered when you close the server, then in such case you can handle it, but in my case I want to look for http connection whether it's alive and if it's not then close the stream

Comment: @A.Z. you were right, shutdown can detect connection closing, but I tested it wrongly. Here's answer for this question https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/discussions/2552, but basically your answer is correct as well.